# Assembler ARM Force a boolean method to return always TRUE

Tags: assembly, arm, patch, ida

That's the end of my code that I thing contain the return function.

```
MOVW            R1, #0x7368
ADD             R0, PC  ; 
MOVT.W          R1, #0xF
ADD             R1, PC ; 
LDR             R0, [R0] ; 
LDR             R1, [R1] ; 
LDR             R0, [R4,R0]
BLX             _objc_msgSend
MOVW            R1, #0x7DC4
MOV             R2, R8
MOVT.W          R1, #0xF
MOV             R3, R6
ADD             R1, PC ; 
LDR             R1, [R1] ; "
BLX             _objc_msgSend
LDR.W           R8, [SP+0x10+var_10],#4
POP             {R4-R7,PC}
```

Can someone comment what it do and explain me how to force the return instruction that I think it's the POP to always return TRUE!

The part of code that I poste... is a Boolean function that makes some operation and than return TRUE or FALSE.

Thanks

Comment: That looks like a chunk of compiled Objective C code for iOS - why not just modify the source code ?

Comment: yes it is! I can do what I want because that the function is mine and it is in one of my project... if I ask the question is only for curiosity... I already create a tweak that can intercept that method and replace the return value with a TRUE! Now I want to understand how can I do the same thing by patching the executable... can you help me?

Comment: If you step through the function in the Xcode debugger you can get to the return statement in the function and then look at the corresponding ARM assembly. Or you can do this will gdb/lldb, whichever you prefer. Also post the Objective C source code for the function in your question above and maybe someone can give further help with this.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler follows the Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture then the return value is passed in `R0`. The `POP` instruction restores other registers and loads the `PC` to return to the calling function, but it does not load `R0`. If you want the function to always return a Boolean true then you need to add an instruction before the `POP` that loads `R0`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Can you complete your answer by adding the code to loads the R0 register?

Comment: Thanks! but in my case why not the value that will be returned isn't in R0?